# Confuse about Robot Framework data-driven sample? What is "C${}="?

Tags: python, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I have done some research about this syntax but I can't find a meaning of it.

[image]

- Could someone explain a little bit more of this "C${expression}="?
- How is this different with ${expression}?

Thank you in advance.

original file is: https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/robotdemo/src/51f472687b6a46e88b7c179423f0f336e19497fc/data_driven.robot?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, `C${expression}=` is the string "C", followed by whatever is in the variable ${expression}, followed by the string "=".

This code has a keyword named `Push buttons` which takes as a single argument a string of characters representing buttons. When you call `Calculate` with an argument like `2+4`, `${expression}` will be `2+4`, so `C${expression}=` is the string `C2+4=`. The `Push Buttons` keyword will then simulate pressing "C", "2", "+", "4", and "=".

Comment: Thanks that's help. :)